# PHP SOAP returning wrong values to clients

Tags: c#, php, soap

I'm trying to return a value from my (MySQL) database to a C# client, through SOAP.

The server is written in PHP, which I think is where everything goes wrong:

```
class foo{
    function bar()
    {
        $result = $connection->query("SELECT value
                                      FROM table 
                                      WHERE id='$id'");

        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        return (int)$row['value'];
    }
}
```

Will turn up as 0 in C#, no matter what value was in the database. However,

```
class foo{
    function bar()
    {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

turns up as the correct value (5 in this case) in C#.

What am I missing here? It seems that data from the database will not be returned to C# correctly, but any other ways of writing the same value (statically) in PHP, will succeed.

EDIT:
I've now set up a PHP SOAP-client, which receives the same values as C# does. So it seems that the problem is with the PHP SOAP-server, communicating the wrong values to the client (whenever the value to return is not static).

EDIT:
I have now found the solution to my problem; My WSDL file had a complex request type, even though it only required a simple type. Changing this complex type to a simple type, fixed the problem. Do not ask me why - it does not make the slightest sense to me!

Comment: Can you log the value in PHP before returning from `bar`? What happens if you call `bar` from a non-c# client?

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo The value is displayed correctly, when bar is called from another PHP script (not over SOAP).
I have not tried other types of SOAP-clients, than the C# one.

Comment: I would take a look at the proxy class that VS.NET generated. I do not understand how PHP tells SOAP consumers that the return type is `int`. Is there some meta description for the PHP functions present?

Comment: First check what's actually transmitted on the wire (with a tool such as Fiddler or Wireshark).

Comment: @Uwe Keim I'm not sure that I understand your question; I'm using a WSDL document, to define the types that are to be returned from the SOAP-requests.

Comment: Are you transmitting the $id parameter? Does it get into the query? (Possible case of SQL injection vulnerability). By the way, who uses PHP as the service server and .NET as the client? It's supposed to be the other way around :)

Comment: @AlexanderMP The value that I'm looking to retrieve from the database IS retrieved correctly. When I var_dump the return of bar(), from a PHP call (not through SOAP), I get the correct value.

Also, I escape $id before it's inserted into the query, in my "real code". :-)

Comment: I'm with driis on this one but you could try Soap Tracer from the Microsoft SOAP Toolkit as this will probably be easier to setup then a full fledged network sniffer.

Comment: It appears that the value isn't transmitted correctly. Simple as that. Something wrong with communication, with SOAP. Seems clear.

Comment: @AlexanderMP It seems that you are right; I've just set up a PHP SOAP client, which receives the exact same (wrong) values, as C#.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for an associative array. This may return more that one item.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
The solution was something in the WSDL document, as you can read in the first post.
Also, it is not possible for bar() to return more than one item, since id (obviously?) is unique, and I'm only returning 'value' from the  array.